# How do i write a Regular Expression to match text containing XYZ but not ABC?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to write a regex that matches if a string contains XYZ but doesn't contain ABC somewhere before it. So "blah XYZ blah" should match, but "blah ABC blah XYZ blah " should not.

Any ideas? In particular I'm writing the regex in c#, in case there's anything specific to that syntax.

I guess I can use negative lookbehind but haven't used this before...

thanks!

UPDATE: I need a regex as I don't have the ability to modify the code, just some configuration.

UPDATE: Changed as I actually only need to check that ABC doesn't appear *before* XYZ, I don't need to check if it comes after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for lookbehind:

```
^(?:(?!ABC).)*XYZ
```

Answer (score 4):

```
^(?:(?<!ABC).)*XYZ
```

was fine for my little testset.

Comment: “ABCXYZ” would also be matched.

Comment: NB: I ended up using "(?si)^(?:(?<!ABC).)*XYZ", where s makes . match newlines and i makes it case-insensitive. The multiline option is important to be off too, so ^ matches start of string instead of start of lines.

Comment: Actually, Alan M's answer without lookbehind is perhaps faster.

Comment: @Rory: don't hesitate to change the accepted answer if one seems better! :-) I admit I don't know if one is faster or not. And it probably doesn't matter, unless you have megabytes of data to check.

Answer (score 2):

is there anything wrong with

```
 string.Contains("XYZ") && !string.contains("ABC")
```

Comment: Both sub strings can be within the string, just not in a certain order.

Comment: the OP is in the unfortunate situation of NEEDing regex though :(

Answer (score 0):

that should do the trick:

```
^([^(ABC)]*)(XYZ)(.*)$
```

some examples:

```
sadsafjaspodsa //False
sadABCdsaABCdsa //False
sadABCdsaABCdsaXYZ //False
sadABCdsaABCdsaXYZaa //False
sadABCddasABCsaXYZdsa //False
sadsaXYZdsa //True
sadsaXYZ //True
```

Comment: @PhiLho: your case should be false.

Comment: @J.J.: PhiLho is right, if any of a given characters from ABC appears before XYZ my expression fails

Comment: Parentheses, too:

sad()dsaXYZasd // False

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
^(?:(?!ABC).{3,})?XYZ
```

And if it also should not appear after `XYZ`:

```
^(?:(?!ABC).{3,})?XYZ(?:.{3,}(?<!ABC))?$
```